# Shapes(rectangle,diamond) detection using OpenCV library

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, shapes

I have two connected rectangles with a diamond in between them. In Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) we have the same scenario. My aim is to detect both the rectangles and the diamond which is in between them.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# reading image
img = cv2.imread('pic4.jpeg')

# converting image into grayscale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# setting threshold of gray image
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# using a findContours() function
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
    threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

i = 0

# list for storing names of shapes
for contour in contours:

    # here we are ignoring first counter because
    # findcontour function detects whole image as shape
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
        continue

    # cv2.approxPloyDP() function to approximate the shape
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(
        contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    
    # using drawContours() function
    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)

    # finding center point of shape
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M['m00'] != 0.0:
        x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

    # putting shape name at center of each shape
    if len(approx) == 3:
        cv2.putText(img, 'Triangle', (x, y),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    elif len(approx) == 4:
        cv2.putText(img, 'Rectangle', (x, y),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    elif len(approx) == 5:
        cv2.putText(img, 'Pentagon', (x, y),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    elif len(approx) == 6:
        cv2.putText(img, 'Hexagon', (x, y),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)

    else:
        cv2.putText(img, 'circle', (x, y),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (255, 0, 0), 2)

# displaying the image after drawing contours
cv2.imshow('pic4', img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input image

[image: Input image]

Output image after shapes detection

[image: Image after detection]

The output image is not detecting correct shape. It must have to write a rectangle once in both rectangle shapes.

Comment: In that image you posted - where is the diamond?

Comment: it would be in between those 2 rectangles in place of the line and the text which is written on line would be written inside the diamond

Comment: It's going to identify all of the words and numbers as shapes, as well it should.  It's up to YOU to process the list of contours and figure out which ones are large enough to be your flowchart shapes.

Comment: You need [Shape Descriptors/Features](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html). You could use the Aspect Ratio, Min and Max Axes Ratio (via extreme points) or maybe Convexity Defects. You could build a simple feature vector and measure its distance to what you expect for each shape.

Comment: those two pictures don't match. are they supposed to ("before/after")?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz He changed the images. He originally uploaded the "Output image" without annotations, mentioning a diamond that wasn't there. He updated the input image but left the result of the previous input.

Comment: @stateMachine kindly brief me in simple words plz bcz computer vision is actually not my field and its been tough for me to handle this situation